# htaccess redirect based on query value (range of values)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a bunch of pages from one domain to another (not all the pages, just part of them).

The URL of a page is domain.com/?p=ID

ID is always a number.

I'd like to redirect all pages with IDs under 2000 a new domain, say domain2.com/?=ID

How can I do it? I'll probably have to use REGEX patterns, but I'm not that savvy when it comes to REGEX.

Thanks,

Roy

Comment: If your IDs would had better structure, then you could use "lexicographically precedes" functionality of `RewriteCond` directive, but it will not work with IDs like 1, 30, 2000 .. as it's a simple string comparison and 30>2000 (yep, it's a string comparison, not numbers). If your IDs would have 0030 instead of 30, then it would work, as 0030<2000. **Therefore** the best approach would be to handle such redirect in your script (index.php or whatever you have there).

Answer (score 0):

It is probably possible to do with a regex but regex is not really suited to doing ranges like that. Another way to do it could be to use a RewriteMap in your Apache conf like so:

```
RewriteMap examplemap txt:/path/to/file/map.txt
RewriteRule ^/?p=(.*) ${examplemap:$1|/?p=$1}
```

Your `/path/to/file/map.txt` file would then contain something like:

```
1 http://domain2.com/?p=1
2 http://domain2.com/?p=2
3 http://domain2.com/?p=3
.
.
2000 http://domain2.com/?p=2000
```

If the entry is not found in the map file then it should default to the existing domain because of the part after the pipe in the RewriteRule. This might seem like an overkill but it gives you the finest level of control over each redirect.

The above code has not been tested but hopefully it explains the principal. See the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/rewritemap.html) for more information on using RewriteMap.

Comment: RewriteMap is really bad approach here, considering the number of similar URLs... Much better to do it in the actual script (index.hp of whatever he has there).

Comment: Agreed that RewriteMap does not seem like a fantastic approach but I think it is better than using a regex, which will get messy and difficult to understand. Maybe writing custom code in the app itself is a better approach assuming you have access to it.

Comment: I have access to the script, solved it by handling the redirect via a few lines of PHP code in my site's header file. Thanks for the help.